# Why am I getting significant lag on Lili: Child of Geos when my gaming laptop exceeds all its requirements?

Tags: performance, system-requirements, lili-child-of-geos

After checking with [Can You Run It?](http://www.systemrequirementslab.com/cyri/requirements/lili-child-of-geos/12139/?p=a), I appear to exceed the requirements for the game. Oddly enough, Can You Run It asks me to upgrade even though I exceed the recommended requirements:

[image]

Is there any way that I can optimize the game? Or could it be because I'm playing a 32-Bit game on a 64-Bit PC?

Comment: The reason it's flagging the CPU is because the i5-2400S is a 3.4Ghz CPU and it likely doesn't like mobile GPUs and/or thinks your video card drivers are out of date.  However, I don't know enough about this specific game to suggest settings to change to improve performance.

Comment: Minimum means you can *run* the game.  Probably not perfectly, but it'll work.  Recommended is usually what you need to play it properly.  Looks like you don't have the recommended.

Comment: Is the game *actually* lagging or are you just judging by "Can you run it" results? Because those only compare your computer against the min req specs and those rarely include mobile parts.

Comment: I played the game, found that it lags, and then went to "Can You Run It". It's odd that I don't have recommended, as my stats seem to be higher than recommended (except for the 3.4GHz thing)

Comment: Did you make sure you were using nvidia gpu instead of the integrated intel gpu?

Comment: @Chippies Thank you so much good sir, the game runs perfectly now, on highest settings. My silly machine must have been using the integrated GPU instead. May I accept your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're on a laptop, it is very possible that you are using the integrated gpu, rather than the much more powerful dedicated nvidia gpu, because your laptop is more than capable of running the game at acceptable performance.
You can change it in the nvidia control panel in the "Manage 3D settings" menu like this:
[image]